# How to parse an optional flag as a Maybe value?

Tags: haskell, command-line-arguments, applicative, optparse-applicative

I'm trying to use [optparse-applicative](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative-0.11.0.2) to parse a `Maybe String` but I can't find anywhere how to deal with `Maybe`. The only thing I found is to add a default value but I really need a `Nothing` if user didn't supply an option instead of `""`. Is there any way to achieve this ?

Here is an example of working code:

```hs
import Options.Applicative

data Config = Config
    { cIn :: String
    , cOut :: String
    } deriving Show

configParser :: Parser Config
configParser = Config
    <$> strOption (long "in" <> short 'i')
    <*> strOption (long "out" <> short 'o')


main :: IO ()
main = do
    conf <- execParser (info configParser fullDesc)
    print conf
```

However, I would like the parameters to be optional and use `Maybe String` instead of `String` in `Config` :

```
data Config = Config
    { cIn :: Maybe String
    , cOut :: Maybe String
    } deriving Show
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

See the following passage of the [`optparse-applicative` README](https://github.com/pcapriotti/optparse-applicative/blob/master/README.md):

> Parsers are instances of both `Applicative` and `Alternative`, and work
>   with any generic combinator, like `many` and `some`. For example, to make
>   a option return `Nothing` instead of failing when it's not supplied, you
>   can use the `optional` combinator in `Control.Applicative`:
>
> ```
> optional $ strOption
>    ( long "output"
>   <> metavar "DIRECTORY" )
> ```

Accordingly, all you have to do is apply the `optional` combinator to the result of `strOption`:

```hs
import Options.Applicative

data Config = Config
    { cIn  :: Maybe String
    , cOut :: Maybe String
    } deriving Show

configParser :: Parser Config
configParser = Config
    <$> (optional $ strOption $ long "in" <> short 'i')
    <*> (optional $ strOption $ long "out" <> short 'o')

main :: IO ()
main = do
    conf <- execParser (info configParser fullDesc)
    print conf
```

Tests at the command line:

```
$ main --in foo -o bar
Config {cIn = Just "foo", cOut = Just "bar"}
$ main -i foo
Config {cIn = Just "foo", cOut = Nothing}
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason this example has been deleted from the README so this answer is the only way to learn how to do this very basic thing.

Comment: @mgiuca You're welcome. To be fair, the wording has changed and the example is gone, but a description of `optional` can still be found at the end of [this section](https://github.com/pcapriotti/optparse-applicative/blob/master/README.md#alternative).